# php export to excel does not work in IE in website

Tags: php, internet-explorer, export-to-excel

I am trying to export data from database to an excel sheet, using php and mysql.
It works fine in my localhost in IE and all browsers, but fails in the real website in IE (a hostmonster site). It says the file could not be downloaded.

This is my sample code that generates dynamic data and offers download:

```
<?php
while($node_stmt = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $contents.="\t\t".$node_stmt['uniqueid']."\t";          
    $contents.=$node_stmt['title'].' '.
    ucfirst($node_stmt['firstname']).' '.
    ucfirst($node_stmt['lastname'])."\t";

        $contents.=$node_stmt1['topic']."\t";
        $contents.=$abst."\t";
        $contents.=$node_stmt['email']."\t";
        $contents.=$node_stmt['phoneno']."\t";
        $contents.=$pay."\t";
        $contents.=$node_stmt['state_id']."\t";
        $contents.=$node_stmt['country_id']."\n";
    }

.....

header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: none');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;'); // This should work for IE & Opera
header("Content-type: application/x-msexcel"); // This should work for the rest
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');

echo $contents; 
?>
```

Do i need to change any settings with the host or IE?

Comment: Have you tried not sending application/x-msexcel to ie, and instead only send application/vnd.ms-excel? Just do a simple if check on $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$filename ='excelreport.xls';
$contents = "testdata1 \t testdata2 \t testdata3 \t \n";
header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
echo $contents;
```

Comment: This is almost working, but i had to add few additional headers for making it work in IE.

header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');

Answer (score 1):

You file is not `application/vnd.ms-excel` nor is it `application/x-msexcel` it's `text/tab-separated-values` http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/tab-separated-values

However that mime type may not be well known so use `text/csv` which will work OK for tsv as well.

Also when you do `Content-Disposition: attachment` it means to save the file. If you want browsers to open it in excel you need `inline`. (Some browsers let the user override this, some don't.)